# AWS: Create a CloudTrail in boto3 that logs only write activity in all S3 bucket within an account

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

The following boto3 code creates a trail. How can it be modified in a way to log only the Write Activity that happens on all S3 buckets within the account?

```
trail_name = 'PUT_TRAIL_NAME_HERE'
bucket_name = 'PUT_BUCKET_NAME_HERE'
is_all_region_trail = True
read_write_type = 'WriteOnly' # How to force the trail to only log Write Activity?
prefix = 'logs'


import boto3

def create_cloudtrail(trail_name, bucket_name, is_all_region_trail, read_write_type, prefix):
    client = boto3.client('cloudtrail')

    response = client.create_trail(
        Name=trail_name,
        S3BucketName=bucket_name,
        IsMultiRegionTrail=is_all_region_trail,
        EnableLogFileValidation=True,
        S3KeyPrefix=prefix
        # Can We use some parameter to set the trail to log 'WriteOnly' Activity?
    )

    return response
```

I could not find a parameter in create_trail method.